# Proving that one function is a multiple of another using derivatives

Tags: functions, derivatives, roots

a) Show that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial such that $P(a)=P'(a)=0$ then there exists a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that $P(x)=(x-a)^2Q(x).$

I know that the tangent line to P at a is horizontal at (a,0), which means (x-a) is a factor of P, but I can't seem to prove if $(x-a)^2$ is a factor of P.

Comment: Hint:  first write $P(x)=(x-a)p_1(x)$.  What is $P'(x)$ in terms of $p_1(x)$?  Can you show that $P'(a)=0\implies  p_1(a)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate,
$$ P'(x)= 2 (x-a) Q(x)+(x-a)^2 Q'(x) $$
at $x=a$
$$ P'(a)=0$$
for all $Q,Q'$